# Editing file in External Storage

Tags: java, android, file, edit, android-external-storage

In my app, I am writing a file and storing it in external storage

But everytime I want to edit it, I have to get the data of file, delete it and then recreate it using the new data.

But is there any way to directly edit a existing file instead of deleteing and recreating it?

Comment: are you writing large amount of data into that file?

Comment: open it in APPEND_MODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **blackbelt** for helping me out.

Here is how to do this -

```
File gpxfile = new File(File address, "filename.txt");

    BufferedWriter bW;

    try {
        bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(gpxfile));
        bW.write("file text");
        bW.newLine();
        bW.flush();
        bW.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This will rewrite the file. If you just want to add a line instead of replacing the whole thing, then replace

```
bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(gpxfile));
```

with

```
bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(gpxfile, true));
```